# 422 error on ajax request to patch 'update' action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I currently have an events model, controller and views.
I have a modal that updates an event. It sends an ajax request to the update action.
However i am currently receiving a '422 (Unprocessable Entity)' from the ajax request.

The request is not even hitting the controller action. (I have a binding.pry at the top of the update action)

Im not sure why this is not working, as i use the same ajax request for the creation of an event as well.

Ajax request:

```html
  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: "PATCH",
    data: data,
    success: this.onAjaxSuccess.bind(this),
    failure: function (error) {
      debugger
      console.log(error)
    }
  });
```

the form action is:
`/events/1`

I've tried to hit the update action by removing any unnecessary code like the data, but still not luck. Also i have seen a couple of posts suggesting to `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`, but that also did not work.

I'm not sure on the next steps so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check your server logs, the line after the initial request will tell you which controller and action your form is hitting. Once you know that you can start debugging - if it tries to go to the correct controller and action but doesn't hit your pry-point then you have a before_action in that controller returning the 422

Comment: Yep you're right. It was a before action problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from Mark in the comments.
It was a `before action` problem.
I had a check that used to be needed which i forgot to remove.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request may need csrf-token, build your update form with Rails helper, then add header to request

```
headers: {
  'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```